# Split values from a jQuery CSV from an AutoSuggest jQuery code

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I am currently using - http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin for an autosuggest on my site. I have limited the number of choices to 3.

This is the autosuggest code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[id=category]").autoSuggest("http://localhost:8888/bl/pages_mx/category_1.php",      
{selectedItemProp: "name", selectedValuesProp: "value", searchObjProps: "name", 
minChars: 1, matchCase: false, selectionLimit: 3});
});
</script>
```

The categories the visitor can choose is taken from a table within the MYSQL database. I can now successfully see the suggestions when I begin to type in potential categories!

The 2 values that are queried from the 'category' table are - category_ID and name.

My question is, once the user has chosen their 1,2 or 3 choices, how can I get the category_ID in 3 different variables in php, or in an array?

The closest I have got to help on their discussion forum is by using this code:

```
var arr = $(".as-values").val().split(",");
```

But from there, I have no idea how to implement this?

I have tried using an explode function to split the CSV using this:

```
<?php if($_POST['category_submit']){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = $(".as-values").val().split(",");
var exploded = arr.split(',');
var category_1=exploded[0];
var category_2=exploded[1];
var category_3=exploded[2];
print (category_1);
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

But nothing seems to print when I press submit?

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Many thanks!

But nothing seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's important to write JavaScript when writing JavaScript.  "Print" is not a valid line of JavaScript.

Second, when you call `.split()`, what you get is an array that's immediately indexable.

```
var arr = $(".as-values").val().split(",");
var category_1=arr[0];
var category_2=arr[1];
var category_3=arr[2];
```

Comment: Right I see, this is fantastic. So from the var category_1, how will I be able to store them in a php variable? by a simple assign? category_1 = $category_1. This is so I can update the database.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between javascript (client-side) and PHP (server-side).  They cannot directly talk back and forth and instead must go through a service.  You're a long way away from making that happen, I suggest reading through tutorials like this one: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/.  Please mark my response as the answer if it was helpful.